# Handlebody Decomposition of a torus seems to follow Pascal's triangle

Tags: algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I have been studying Morse Theory and found something really cool that I have no idea how to prove. The handlebody decomposition of a 2-torus is a 0-handle, two 1-handles, and one 2-handle. Similarly, the handlebody decomposition of a 3-torus is a 0-handle, three 1-handles, three 2-handles and one 3-handle. It seems like it follows Pascal's triangle. Does anyone know if this is true and if so, is there any intuition for this?

Comment: Just take the product Morse function on $T^n=S^1\times\dots \times S^1$ and look at what you get.